# npm run build generates build folder without index.html

Tags: reactjs, build

This is my first react app and I am trying to deploy it. When i use npm run build command, it produces all the folders in /build except index.html.

As a result, browser only renders file path on my localhost port.

P.S: I tried my best to find the solution to this issue, ut I couldn't and there is one very close which is related to VUEjs not reactjs

**I do use create-react-app**

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-task-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "serve": "^14.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "homepage": "."
  }
}
```

Comment: `npm run build` can be anything. You should show what is it in `package.json`. Also, do you use `create-react-app`?

Comment: added. 
Yes I do.